# Proof that a "$4$-word" can't exist in a recursive sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, contest-math

In the proof to the problem below, I'm not able to understand what they've done for the case $(c)=1977$?  How did they know that $1977$ implied that there are only finitely many $4$-words?  And why is invertibility relevant here?

---

[image]

Comment: I think there's a word missing in the very first sentence; it should be 'every digit from the fifth on is the sum of the preceeding _four_ digits mod 10'. Otherwise, I don't see how one gets the '7' at the sixth position in the sequence.

Comment: Ya, I figured the sequence makes sense if you just sum the $4$ prior terms to get the next term

Comment: Also, (c) is trivial as written - we have already seen that the word '1977' appears in the sequence!

Comment: If it were that trivial then why did he spend so much time discussing the periodicity.  I think he meant does it occur later in the sequence.  Guess he wasn't careful with the wording of the question.  Besides that, I get that there are only so many $4$-words that can exist but that doesn't imply that every $4$-word will show up multiple times.  I guess the part I'm not grasping the part about $4$-words determining prior terms determining prior sequences, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not written very clearly.

The fact that there are only finitely many distinct possible $4$-words in a sequence is obvious, since there are only finitely many possible $4$-words, period! The number of possible distinct words is $10^4$.

Any deterministic process on finitely many states must eventually fall into a period. If you start at some specific state $w_0$ and proceed according to the rule (whatever rule) to switch to states $w_1, w_2, w_3, \ldots$ since there are only finitely many possible distinct states, at some point some $w_N$ must equal some earlier $w_M$, with $M<N$. From this point onwards things repeat themselves.

The distinction made here is between a pure cycle, which is the case $M=0$, and a non-pure one, which is the case $M>0$. In words, did you come back to the very first state, or to some other state? That's what these two diagrams depict: a pure circle or a figure-6.

Invertibility is relevant because in an invertible transformation, the figure-6 case is impossible. See why? At the junction there, two states merge into the same state. This means that the process is *not* invertible. Put differently, if a process *is* invertible, meaning distinct states yield distinct outcomes, then from any given starting point you must always come back to that very starting point. You can't find yourself cycling in some smaller cycle.

In this particular case, what this means is that starting with $1,9,7,7$ you must eventually come back to $1,9,7,7$, and the word just before that must be $0,1,9,7$, and therefore both $1977$ and $0197$ are bound to show up infinitely many times in this infinite sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!  How should I prove the operation is injective?  if $f(a_i)=f(b_i)$, where $a_i=a_1a_2a_3a_4$, and $b_i=b_1b_2b_3b_4$ then $f(a_i)=a_2a_3a_4(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)$.  I'm not sure how I'd proceed to prove injectivity?  Or should I prove invertibility using a different theorem?  and isn't it enough to show that the operation is injective and not surjective?  I don't see why every possible $4$-word shows up in the sequence.

Comment: @johnfowles Invertibility is most easily proved by just explicitly constructing an inverse; if $a_5=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$, then $a_1=a_5-(a_2+a_3+a_4)$. Thus, just as given the four-digit sequence $a_1a_2a_3a_4$ we can find the next digit $a_5$, if we have the sequence $a_2a_3a_4a_5$ we can explicitly find the next digit $a_1$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Awesome!  Thanks for this